# Has HTTP bogus request type "COOK" been used in any known website attacks?

Tags: http, apache

An apache web server access weblog shows a request type "COOK" where POST or GET are normally found.  Is such a request part of any known web-based site attacks?

Comment: I think [this can answer your question](http://serverfault.com/questions/579124/what-is-http-cook-request-method-in-my-logs).

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf that's the top hit in my Google search, too

Answer (score 1):

As @WhiteWinterWolf mentioned, Pepoluan answered [over here on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/579124/what-is-http-cook-request-method-in-my-logs):

> The COOK verb appears to be synonymous with the User-Agent string containing "Synapse". The term Synapse is a free TCP/IP library written in Pascal (see here: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Synapse#From_an_HTTP_server) that is used to create bots, scrapers and crawlers as well as other legitimate software.